# Change another binding out of a custom bindingHandler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I change out of a custom bindingHandler(fadeVisible) the value of another binding (isFadingIn). Best explained with an example.

```
<div data-binding="fadeVisible: isVisible; fadingIn: isFadingIn; animationDuration: 500">...</div>


ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.unwrap(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out

        var duration = allBindings.get('animationDuration') || 400;
        //vvvvvvvvv here
        allBindings.get('fadingIn') = true;

        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).fadeIn(duration).then(function () {
           //vvvvvvvvv here
           allBindings.get('fadingIn') = false;
        }) : $(element).fadeOut(duration).then(function () {
           //vvvvvvvvv here
           allBindings.get('fadingIn') = false;
        });
    }
};
```

**Edit**: changed Parameters

```
(element, valueAccessor)
```

to

```
(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allBindings` argument is missing from the function signature. `allBindings.get`will return an observable, so you should set it like an observable:

```
allBindings.get('fadingIn')(true);
allBindings.get('fadingIn')(false);
```

Comment: Ok thx, this is helping with the understanding. But i'm not sure if this is the best option. I wouldn't be able to use the custom bindingHandler two times in the same View/ViewModel.

Comment: I understood that you wanted to change `IsFadingIn` of the binded viewmodel to `true` by writing `allBindings.get('fadingIn') = true;`. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What do you mean by 'two times'?

Comment: I want to be able to bind a observable of the ViewModel to the fadingIn binding. If I access directly the ViewModel all fadeVisible bindings, will update the same observable.

Comment: If I understand it the right, I need a valueAccessor of the binding. This seems to be working like a observable. valueAccessorFadingIn(true);

Comment: Never mind what I said before. You're missing the `allBindings` argument in the function and you should write `allBindings.get('fadingIn')(true);`